# Comparing player percentages effectiveness with different sample sizes

Tags: binary-data, ranking

I have a spreadsheet of player data. One of the categories of player data is pass percentage. Pass percentage is calculated as follows:

```
AccuratePasses/TotalPasses
```

In total I have around 400 players to compare, however the sample size of passes between each player is very different. For example on player may have executed 1592 passes (1426 of which were accurate), and another may have executed only 7 passes (of which all were accurate).

How can I use the data I have to extrapolate a score or ranking based on the player effectiveness or likelihood of being effective. At the moment I have a formula to do this as follows:

```
PlayerAccuratePasses-(PlayerTotalPasses*(AverageAccuratePasses/AverageTotalPasses)
```

I did not pull this formula together and want to be sure that this makes sense mathematically to produce a score of who is the most effective passer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best way to takle the problem is to take a Bayesian approach.

Your scoring metric $S$ is going to be the expectation of the parameter of a Bernouilli distribution which represents the intrinsic accuracy of the player.
As a prior distribution, you can take the conjugate prior that is the [beta distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution) with parameter $\alpha$ and $\beta$. You choose them such as expectation and variance are equal to the sample mean and sample variance of the data.

The final posterior expectation of the accuracy becomes (using [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_prior)):

$S=E(\Theta) = \frac{\alpha + n_{acc}}{\alpha + \beta + n_{tot}}$

where $n_{acc}$ (resp. $n_{tot}$) is the number of accurate (resp. total) passes of the player considered.

The formula behaves quite nicely if the number of passes $n_{tot}$ is low / high.

Comment: This looks interesting thanks. I am not sure however what α and β represent in the formula, or how to calculate then. Same with Θ. Had a look through the wikipedia links but couldn't spot anything, although I may have been looking in the wrong place.

Comment: On the link for the beta distribution, you can find the expression for the mean and variance of the distribution as functions of $\alpha$ and $\beta$. You can solve them in order to match the sample mean and sample variance of your data.

Comment: Thanks, I have tried this - but not sure I am getting it right! Here is what I have done

`TP = TotalPassesAllPlayers`
`ATP = Average(TP)`
`v = (ATP*(1-ATP))/VARP(TP))-1`
`α = ATP*v`
`β = (ATP-1)*v`

Then with these using your formula above
`(α+ThisPlayerAccuratePasses)/(α+β+ThisPlayerTotalPasses)`

Sorry if I am being a little slow, my maths experience doesn't strech much past GCSE so this is quite complicated for me :)

Comment: $\frac{\alpha}{\alpha + \beta} = m = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n n_{acc}^i / n_{tot}^i$, $\frac{\alpha}{(\alpha + \beta)^2(\alpha + \beta + 1)} = v = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n (n_{acc}^i / n_{tot}^i - m)^2$. $v$ and $m$ can be calculated from your data. Then solve for $\alpha$ and $\beta$

Comment: See the section "Parameter Estimation" in the wikipedia link where in your case the $X_i$ represent the sample percentage accuracy (that is $\frac{n_{acc}^i}{n_{tot}^i}$) of the player $i$

Comment: Thanks, think I got it now. I have added it all to a Google Doc so you can see the results [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Ai51XN4eaCGEdFduMF9jYnlKLVBmOEJsV0sxUkVLTkE). Comparing the version using the formula you have given me vs the one I was given with the data the players who have a very small sample size still seems to be performing well in comparison. Have a done something wrong?

Comment: I checked and you made a small mistake when copying the wikipedia formulas: you forgot to divide by $m$ in the formula for $\beta$. To verify your result you need to check that $\frac{\alpha}{\alpha + \beta} = m$. Also, for a player with no pass, its score is gonna be $m$ as well. Let me know what you think of the new score after the correction.

Comment: Also, if you find that the value of the parameter $\alpha$ and $\beta$ still give too much credit for player with only a small number of passes, nothing prevent you from decreasing the prior variance, that is change $v \leftarrow \frac{1}{2}v$ for example.

Comment: So β = ((1-mean)/α)/m ? I have tried to formulate m as suggested above but it doesn't seem to equal the forumla. Again, thanks for your patience on this - sorry if I am being dim.

Comment: The formula for $\beta$ in your spreadsheet must be ((1-B2)*D2)/B2.

Comment: Thanks, changed it to that and changed the power of the variance and it seems to be coming up with a good result now. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be conflating a measure with its margin of error.

Passer accuracy is measured by the first fraction you quote:

AccuratePasses/TotalPasses

You can then look at things like confidence intervals to see how well estimated the proportion is.

I think trying to combine them into one measure is a mistake, but you could, I suppose, compare the lower confidence limit (not necessarily 5%, could be some other number).