# Minimum sample size

Tags: confidence-interval, sample-size

Probably a basic question, but here goes:

- Suppose we have 1000 people who respond to a survey (500 men, 500 women)
- Respondents can choose to "like" a series of pages.
- Each respondent can "like" as many pages as they want; it is possible to never like anything.
- For page 1, 200 men like it and 150 women like it.
- For page 2, 300 women like it and 50 men like it.
- For page 3, 4 women like it and 1 man likes it.

My general question is: for small response scenarios (i.e., page 3), what is the minimum sample size before I can really make a conclusion about the male/female general interest?

I can compute a z-score, but I am not sure if it takes this "sub population" into account (I may be confused about this).  I know that my definition of significance will depend on what error rate and confidence I can tolerate, but let us suppose it's the standard confidence interval (95%)

Comment: What would it mean here to "make a conclusion about the male / female general interest"? Are you wondering how much data you need to get a 'significant' result that men & women differ if the true proportions are 4/1k & 1/1k?

Comment: Unless the survey is a *random* sample, the answer is simple: the minimum sample size is almost all the population (enough to be sure that if you could sample the rest of the population, then *no matter what* the responses were, your conclusion would not change). For instance, people who *choose* to respond--such as people who reply to a Web survey form--do *not* constitute a random sample (or anywhere close to it, usually).

Comment: To address both comments above, if I were to say that "4 times as many women as men like page 3", or "80% of the people that liked page 3 were women", do I need to report an error rate or a confidence interval then?  Intuitively, it just seems like too little data to draw such a conclusion without some sort of disclaimer.  Am I off base?  What if only 1 woman liked the page and no men?   My sense is that the entire population (1000) must somehow play a role in the overall significance of the ratio, but I'm not quite sure statistically how it would work.  Thanks for the input.

Comment: And to be clear in response to gung's point, the answer is yes: I am wondering how much data I would need to get a 'significant' result that men & women differ if the true proportions are 4/1k & 1/1k.

Comment: I think your problem is similar to the one asked there: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/47108/comparing-player-percentages-effectiveness-with-different-sample-sizes/. Could you have a look and tell me if it helps?

Comment: Thanks for the link.  It does seem related, although I think that question and mine are after slightly different things.  In the "player question", the guy seems to be interested in normalizing despite an uneven distribution.  That is also true here to some extent, however I am looking to state something about the probability that such a small (self-selected) response is NOT in fact representative.  I would expect that measure to be in the form of "rate of error", but don't know enough to be sure.  I've wondered if z-score inherently takes this rate into account, but again not sure.